# Why doesn't SharePoint open PDF files?

Tags: 2013, custom-list, pdf

I notice that SharePoint 2013 only opens PDF files within the browser window itself, whereas, PowerPoint and Word open up the application that created it. Can the SharePoint Administrator add a function to allow PDF files to be opened with a PDF reader, or is this not allowed since SharePoint is a Microsoft product and Adobe Acrobat is not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The integration of PDF-Files into SharePoint is actually pretty good

> The SharePoint integration feature allows you to check in or check out PDF files from within Acrobat X or Reader X. When your administrator has enabled SharePoint integration, you click a PDF link in the SharePoint browser user interface to open it in Reader or Acrobat
>   (from [SharePoint configuration | Acrobat X, Reader X](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/sharepoint-configuration-acrobat-x-reader.html))

For the configuration on the SharePoint-Server, please take a look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/planning.html?highlight=sharepoint